# Grass Particle Hair Are Big

Tags: mesh, particles, hair

So Recently I Tried To Put Hair Particles As You Can See But Everytime I Scale The Plane The Hair Particle Gets Wider I Probably miss Something Here I Just Want To Make The Hair Particle Skinnier And Straight Any Help Would Be Appreciated[image]

Comment: It's in hair shape, but I'm guessing you scaled in object mode and didn't apply the scale?

Comment: sometimes when you are pro but forget a very useless mistake , thank you appreciate your help